# Notification icon hide number after click

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, octobercms

I use October and I have made plugin with builder and I just add notification icon in menu.

I want to show "!" if there is a new item and hide "!" if user click that (it open bootstrap modal). And when I add new item it shows "!" again etc... I don't know exactly what is the best way to do this. Thank you if you can help me with this.

Menu:

```
<li>
    <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#itemModal"><i class="fa fa-bell"></i>
        <span>! {{ Item }}</span></a>
</li>
```

Code:

```
function onStart() 
{
   $this['Item'] = Db::table('items')->count();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

for this you need db table and you need to save last seen/click date.

so idea here is like you will add current date when user click `!`, you will show `bootstrap modal` and fire ajax request and set current date.

fire ajax request at that time and add new date for param.

for this you can use CMS default `params table`

```
<?php
use System\Models\Parameter;
....

// something like this in ajax request
Parameter::set('your_plugin_name::items.last_click_date', time() );


// this is when page reload    
use System\Models\Parameter;
function onStart() 
{
    // now
    $lastClickDate = Parameter::get('your_plugin_name::items.last_click_date');
    if($lastClickDate == null) {
        // first time it will just count items directly as user never click on icon
        $count = Db::table('items')->count();
    }
    else {  
        // new this will call next time as user called that modal and we added click date 
        // so we compare if any record added after that date if it is then show `!`
        $count = Db::table('items')->where('created_at', '>', $lastClickDate)->count(); 
    }
    $this['item_count'] = $count; 
    $this['new_items'] = $count > 0 ? true : false;
}
```

> html

```
<li>
    <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#itemModal">
        <i class="fa fa-bell"></i>
        {% if new_items %}
            <span>! {{ item_count }} </span>
        {% endif %}
    </a>
</li
```

please add comment if you face any problem.

Comment: Yeah I made table last_click_date, but I can't get that ajax working properly.

Comment: ok can you share what you done with ajax or its code so i can help you better

Comment: Hi, I don't no exactly how I can fire up that ajax request. Can you tell me little bit more about that?